# Identification of Lagrangian Grassmannian with unitary group

Tags: lie-groups, symplectic-geometry, grassmannian, unitary-matrices, symplectic-linear-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}$
Consider the standard symplectic structure on $\mathbb C^{2n}$ induced by the symplectic matrix $J$. We can write: $$\mathbb C^{2n}=\Ker(J-iI)\oplus \Ker(J+iI)$$
This symplectic decomoposition of $\mathbb C^{2n}$ gives a natural correspondence between Lagrangian subspaces of $\mathbb C^{2n}$ and the unitary group. Mainly, $L\subset\mathbb C^{2n}$ is Lagrangian if and only if there is some unitary map:
$$U:\Ker(J-iI)\rightarrow \Ker(J+iI)$$
Such that $L$ is the graph of $U$. Meaning - $L=\{x+Ux\mid x\in \Ker(J-iI)\}$. The contrary also holds - the graph of such a unitary is always a Lagrangian subspace.

This allows one to identify the Lagrangian Grassmannian with $U(n)$ in some sense. This identification appears a lot in spectral theory, and in symplectic geometry in the context of the Maslov index.
I wanted to ask a question regarding this identification:

I also know that the Lagrangian Grassmannian is diffeomorphic to the homogeneous space $Sp(n)/U(n)$. This means that the identification above of the Lagrangian Grassmannian with $U(n)$ is NOT a diffeomorphism, since one is a complex manifold and one is a real manifold.

Is it at least a homotopy equivalence? (I know that the fundamental groups of $U(n)$ and $Sp(n)/U(n)$ are both $\mathbb Z$)

If not, what is 'interesting' about this correspondence, other than being a bijection? Generally, I'd be happy to read a bit about the meaning of this identification and how one should think about it. I'd be happy to hear your answers to this or see references.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting, but shouldn't the first equation be$$\mathbb{R}^{2n}\otimes\mathbb{C}=\ker(J-iI)+\ker(J-iI)$$If you don't complexify and instead regard $J\pm iI$ as maps $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{C}^{2n}$, then both will have empty kernel.

Comment: @Kajelad You are right, I got confused with the real case and made a silly mistake. I changed the post.